# Give an example of a one-to-one function f(n) that is neither O(n) nor Ω(n) and justify it

Tags: analysis, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I have found a lot of examples of such functions, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199344/a-function-that-is-neither-on-nor-%CE%A9n), but I don't understand how to come up with such and how it is explained/proved like it is done in the top answer to that question.

Could somebody please help me come up with one and explain it to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Something simple like $1-\frac{1}{n}$ is one to one and O(1). It is o(n) whoch you can show by taking the limit.

Comment: @Alex, $1-\frac{1}{n}$ is $O(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A= \{2^{n^2}:n\in \mathbb N\}, B = \{3^{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}.$ On $A$ define $f(2^{n^2}) = 2^n, n=1,2\dots$ On $B$ define $f(3^{n}) = 3^{n^2}, n=1,2\dots$ Then $f$ maps $A\cup B$ bijectively to $f(A\cup B).$

The sets $\mathbb N\setminus (A\cup B)$ and $\mathbb N\setminus f(A\cup B)$ are both countably infinite, so we can choose a bijection $g$ between them.

The function $h=f$ on $A\cup B,$ $h= g$ on $\mathbb N\setminus (A\cup B)$ is then a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N.$ By the first paragraph, $h(n)$ is neither $O(n)$ or $\Omega(n).$